# Formatting date with NSDateFormatter on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, objective-c

Since initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage: is now deprecated,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"%B %d, %Y" allowNaturalLanguage:NO] autorelease];
```

How does one currently format with the same formatting string using 2.2.1?

Answer (score 1):

Pl. use the following steps:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just manually assign to dateFormat and only use "init" instead of "initWithDateFormat:...".

The Natural Language stuff is what appears to be deprecated.